# How much power can nuclear power plants produce?

Tags: nuclear-physics, power

I looked at the power plants with the highest capacity and hydroelectric plants seem to dominate the list. Surely nuclear plants could be far more powerful? I assume they are limited because of political concerns and fears over meltdowns. Is there a limit to how powerful they can become? At some point, are they uncontrollable?

Comment: There are also engineering concerns - you know you have to take them down for maintenance, so would you rather have one giant plant, or 4 large plants. If you take the giant one down, you are making nothing, if you take one large plant down, the other 3 are operating. Plus, you can build the 4 large plants spaced appropriately for the construction crews. A hydropower dam uses multiple turbines, so several can be idled for load reasons, or taken offline for maintenance.

Comment: There is no immediate technological limit. The major limit is usually environmental because there is not enough cooling water available. You can only heat up a river by a few degrees before it is biologically damaged and cooling towers also require large amounts of water. That leaves you with locations near the ocean. See "Fukushima" for the problems with that...

Answer (score 1):

Nuclear power plants are built to provide a certain amount of electrical power to a region.  There's no point to build them big just because you can.  Fission reactors can be "poisoned" by fission products if they are not run at a high power level.  When a reactor's core gets "poisoned", it must be shut down for a time to let these fission products decay enough to permit the reactor to be restarted.

As far as the generating capacity of hydroelectric plants is concerned, having a large installed generating capacity does not mean that the plant is generating this much power 100% of the time.  Parts of the plant may be shut down for maintenance/upgrades or because demand is not there.  The water stays stored behind the dam, available should extra generating capacity be needed.